# Is there any food ingredient that tastes like diesel smells?

Tags: flavor, food-science, smell

I like the smell of diesel, and other heavy oils.

Are there any food ingredients, i.e. safe to eat, that have a taste similar to diesel.

I think it would be an interesting experience to eat or drink something that had a taste that I associate with something that is most definitely not food.

The question was prompted by a dispersible aspirin that has a chemical taste vaguely reminiscent of fuel oil.

A beer or tea that tasted like diesel would be fascinating.

I'd be interested in any other "not food" scents that have food safe sources, beyond the more familiar dichotomy transpiring from butyric acid.

Answer (score 5):

Retsina immediately springs to mind; it's a fortified wine stored in pitch-sealed barrels, and it develops a slightly kerosene-like aroma from that. Certain tequilas and mezcals also have a subtle diesel-like aroma.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that durian fruit has a gas/diesel aroma.

Answer (score 0):

**Weed?**

https://www.leafly.com/strains/sour-diesel

> Sour Diesel, also known as "Sour D" and "Sour Deez," is a popular
> sativa marijuana strain made by crossing Chemdawg and Super Skunk.
> Sour Diesel effects are dreamy, cerebral, fast-acting and energizing.
> This strain features a pungent flavor profile that smells like diesel.

I found a couple of recipes which incorporated this weed variant including one for a [Rob Roy that looked interesting](https://www.vice.com/en/article/z48av9/sour-diesel-weed-infused-rob-roy).

Comment: Sour Diesel, Cherry Pie, Pineapple Express… the world is full of cannabis strains which claim to taste like things other than cannabis. I’ve personally never found one that lived up to the promise.